# What are the logical and arithmetical functions from the 74LS181

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-expression, arithmetic-expressions, boolean-operations

i want to use the 74ls181 in an Project of mine but i can not understand all of the functions of it mentioned in its datasheet.
Could someone please explain this boolean-mess?

[image: 74LS181 Datasheet (PDF) - Texas Instruments]

**EDIT:**

Based on the very helpful answer from Axel Kemper i created this:
[image: no]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table was taken from the Texas Instruments [74ls181 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/sn54s181)?

Assuming from your question tags that you are asking about the logical functions
(explained from top to bottom as in the table):

```
F = NOT(A)            set output to inverse of all A bits
F = NAND(A, B)        inverse AND of inputs
F = OR(NOT(A), B)
F = 1                 set all output bits to 1
F = NOR(A, B)
F = NOT(B)            feed inverse B bits to output
F = NOT(EXOR(A, B))
F = OR(A, NOT(B))
F = AND(NOT(A), B)
F = EXOR(A, B)        output is exclusive or of inputs
F = B                 feed B inputs bits to outputs
F = OR(A, B)          bitwise disjunction
F = 0                 set all output bits to 0
F = AND(A, NOT(B))
F = AND(A, B)         bitwise conjuction 
F = A
```

All functions are implemented 4-bit parallel.
`A`, `B` and `F` each have four signal lines.
`A` and `B` are the four-bit inputs. `F` is the four-bit output.

So, `A=0` for example means `A0=0`, `A1=0`, `A2=0`, `A3=0`

There is a total of 16 different logical functions possible to implement with two inputs and one output. 74ls181 implements all of them.

A truth-table with two inputs and one output has four rows.
Each of the rows has output value 0 or 1. Therefore, a four-bit number defines the function described by the truth-table.
With four bits, 16 functions are possible.

There is a very instructive [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fq0MIJjlGsw) available on the 74ls181.

Comment: Yeah sorry i didnt include any arithmetic tags, but thanks to you i can at least guess the Arithmetic Operations.
So for example AB MINUS 1 is the same as AND(A, B) -1 (in 2's comp), MINUS 1 would be F=1(again in 2's C), AB PLUS (A +B') is AND(A, B) + OR(A, NOT(B)).